# How to structure class with same "behavior" but different parameters?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have classes A, B and C. All these classes will need to have the same "behavior", meaning they will have to implement two functions: `canPerform()` and `perform()`.

To have them under a common type would be easy using an interface, but my issue here is that the `perform` function will have different parameters depending on the class.

- In class A, perform's signature would be: `perform(value1: Int, value2: Int)`
- In class B, perform's signature would be: `perform(entries: List<String>)`
- In class C, perform's signature would be: `perform(value1: String)`

So, they all have the same basic behavior: they can see if they "can perform" and then they can "perform". But, to "perform", they have different parameters.

Is it possible to have them under some sort of common hierarchy? Is there an alternative?

Comment: It might help to investigate some classic design patterns, for example, the [visitor pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor). I think it would help to create a [sealed hierarchy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html), with a subclass for each type of argument that `perform()` will accept.

Comment: So when you call `perform` through the interface, how can you be sure that the implementation's `perform` method can take the arguments you are giving it? You *have* to check the type one way or another. I would leave `perform` out of the interface.

Comment: The fact that these things require different arguments and require checking if they "can perform" (which I assume determines whether "perform" is called) are indications to me that they are not, in fact, related.

Comment: After sleeping over this, I am starting to think the same as you guys, maybe this should not fall under the same interface, or at least not with both functions.

Comment: The answer I'd write would be very much like one by Mr Pro Pop that's been deleted (not sure why): have `perform()` take a single, generic param. When multiple params are needed, that'd be an aggregate class like Pair or Triple, though probably better to create your own data classes, with meaningful param names etc. — they could extend an abstract ‘PerformPerams’ class that's an upper bound for the generic. The caller would of course have to create an instance of the aggregate class with the param(s). — If that doesn't feel right, then as you say maybe a single interface doesn't fit after all.